# Collapsed gibbs sampling in R package lda

Tags: c, r, lda, topic-modeling

I’ve been trying to modify parts the R package lda, specifically the slda.em function. 
At some point, the C function "collapsedGibbsSampler” gets called in slda.collapsed.gibbs.sampler.
Does anyone have the C code for that function? I've looked over Jonathan's github to no avail.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jonathan Chang here's where the code lives 
https://github.com/slycoder/R-lda-deprecated/blob/master/src/gibbs.c#L477